# Facing error in apt-get update for ubuntu 15.04

Tags: updates, 15.04, 14.10, update-manager

Recently I have updated my Ubuntu software version from 14.10 to 15.04 but due to some technical mistake the upgrade was not done properly, when ever I tried to do do the update it is throwing the errors like

```
Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release amd64
  (20141022.1)/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use
  apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot
  be used to add new CD-ROMs

  W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release
  amd64 (20141022.1)/dists/utopic/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages 
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get
  update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
```

These are the errors which was showing and in this error I have noticed that the errors were mentioned as Ubuntu 14.10. But mine is upgraded to 15.04 which i have checked it lately

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

so please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. you will (probably) find lines similar to

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release amd64 (20141022.1)]/ utopic main restricted
```

in there. either add a `#` to the beginning of every such line:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release amd64 (20141022.1)]/ utopic main restricted
```

or delete those lines altoghether.

also make sure there are no other references to `utopic` in there anymore. if there are change them all to `vivid`.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

should then work.

Comment: +1 Recommend just adding a # before the line to avoid any issues down the line :)

Comment: ok. rephrased a bit to make this option the first choice.